# Probability of winning a card game where you draw successive cards until all cards have been drawn

Tags: probability, permutations, card-games

I had this question in an interview a few weeks back and I haven't been able to stop thinking about it since.

There is a deck of cards before you - in the deck are cards on which there is one of three shapes (Square, Triangle, Circle) drawn in one of three colors (Red, Blue, Green). The deck consists of all possible color / shape combos with no duplicates - 9 cards total.

To win the game, you must draw each card in the deck. Each successive card you draw MUST have one property in common with the previously drawn card. E.g. if you draw a Red Triangle, then the next card must either be red or have a triangle on it. If you draw a card that has nothing in common with the previous card, you lose.

What's the probability of winning this game?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: This seems like a job for a computer.  There are only $9!=362880$ different arrangements, it should be a trivial matter to loop over them all and brute force the answer.  Without computer assistance and just a quick glance, I can tell you the probability is not $0$ and is not $1$ as there are clearly ways in which you can win and ways in which you can lose.  More specific than that, however, looks out of reach.

Comment: I suggest:  first work it out for $2$ instead of $3$.  There are only $4!$ ways to sort that deck, so if all else fails you can simply write out all the cases and count.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for computer code and seems a reasonable question to be asked in a coding interview.  The number of cases is not so large that it is unmanageable, only $9!=362880$ outcomes.

That said, I do not as of yet see a clean approach to take with pencil and paper.  Having thrown together some quick and dirty code (*shown below*) I get a value of $1512$ for the three-colors three-shapes case giving then a probability of $\dfrac{1512}{9!}$.  The two-color two-shape case and one-color one-shape case can be found by inspection to be $8$ and $1$ respectively.

We can now plug these numbers in to OEIS.org to see if it is a known sequence and indeed it is.  https://oeis.org/A096970.  We can see how OEIS interprets the problem as counting the number of hamiltonian paths on the [rook graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RookGraph.html) $K_n\square K_n$ though it doesn't elaborate further on the methods used to generate the entries given in the sequence already.  I certainly wouldn't trust my code to be able to generate many more entries in any reasonable amount of time... but then again, I wasn't setting out to do so.

In javascript:

```
function permutator(inputArr) {
   var results = [];

   function permute(arr, memo) {
     var cur, memo = memo || [];

     for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       cur = arr.splice(i, 1);
       if (arr.length === 0) {
         results.push(memo.concat(cur));
       }
       permute(arr.slice(), memo.concat(cur));
       arr.splice(i, 0, cur[0]);
     }

     return results;
   }

   return permute(inputArr);
 }
 count=0; 
 permutator(['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2','B3','C1','C2','C3']).$each(function(p){
      fail=false;
      for(i=1; i<p.length; i++){
           if(p[i][0]!=p[i-1][0] && p[i][1]!=p[i-1][1]){
                fail = true;
                break;
           }
      }
      if(!fail){
           count+=1; console.log(p)
      }
 })
```

(*I use a custom .$each which should be clear how it works.  Adjust accordingly if you wish to run it yourself.  It could also be further adjusted if you wish to create the deck of cards programmatically rather than hardcoding.  Again, I was lazy and just after a quick answer.*)

Comment: I like this approach - I did consider putting together a script to run it, but it actually wasn't a coding interview. Either they were suggesting there does exist a clean paper solution, or they were being a bit unreasonable given the time limit. At any rate, there is some structure. E.g, the sequence where you draw (A=any, C=same color, S = same shape): A, C,C, S, C, C, S, C, C. Is no different from A, S, S, C, S, S, C, S, S. For either of these, there are 9*2*1*2*2*1*1*2*1 corresponding outcomes. Perhaps the paper solution really is just to enumerate the possible 'patterns'.

Comment: @deskie how much time did you have?

Comment: @tetra an hour. There were 60 questions, this was the first and the 9 following this one were derivative / adjustments to this problem. The other 50 were other brain teasers / probability / puzzles.